# How to migrate just ONE Wordpress page to production

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have developed a Wordpress page on localhost which I now need to move to the live site.

How do I go about it without having to upload the whole site?

Comment: Uploading the whole site is the traditional way to go. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Its a large site and I do not want to risk uploading the whole site.

Comment: I don't understand. For a copy of Wordpress to function, it needs to be complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Find the page in the database, export it, then import it on the server.
2. Copy the html over manually.